# Brasero crash burning audio CD

Tags: burning, brasero

I am attempting to burn an audio CD but the project keeps crashing when I attempt to write to media.  Here is the last bit of the .log file:

`BraseroWodim Launching command
BraseroWodim called brasero_job_get_fd_out
BraseroWodim called brasero_job_get_fd_in
BraseroWodim called brasero_job_get_fd_out
BraseroWodim stderr: wodim: Operation not permitted. Warning: Cannot raise RLIMIT_MEMLOCK limits.
BraseroWodim called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroWodim stderr: wodim: Resource temporarily unavailable. Cannot get mmap for 16781312 Bytes on /dev/zero.
BraseroWodim called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroWodim stdout: TOC Type: 0 = CD-DA
BraseroWodim stderr: HUP
BraseroWodim stdout: HUP
BraseroWodim process finished with status 11
BraseroWodim called brasero_job_error
BraseroWodim finished with an error
BraseroWodim asked to stop because of an error
    error       = 0
    message = "no message"
BraseroWodim stopping
Session error : unknown (brasero_burn_record brasero-burn.c:2859)`

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Same Error here, 2 Months ago everything worked fine ...

Comment: See this Topic at Redhat:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1580021

I can confirm that after

    sudo chmod u+s /usr/bin/wodim 

Brasero is burning my image.

Not a clean solution, but a working one...